# AngularJs ng-options with promises issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am creating a page with a form where is it possible to modify a job.
When the page loads the following promise chain is fired which gets the current job data and populates the form.

I am having an issue with the city select because only when the job data is returned will I know the province and city values. At this stage another promise is created to build the city select but when it is resolved the selected value of the cities select -which is populated with cities- is not being set to $scope.job.city not sure why.

```
  api.getJobCategories()
      .then(function (responseObject) {
          $scope.jobCategories = responseObject.data;
          return api.getJob({
              job_id: $routeParams.job_id
          });
      })
      .then(function (responseObject) {
          $scope.job = responseObject.data;
          // $scope.job.city has correct city value
          return api.getProvinceCities({
              province_name: $scope.job.province,
              asJson: true
          });
      })
      .then(function (responseObject) {
          // Issue: $scope.job.city has correct value but after building
          // the cities select $scope.job.city value is not applied to cities select
          $scope.cites = responseObject.data;
      });
```

template

```
<form name="formjob" class="css-form" novalidate>
... more controls

<!-- Issue job.city model value does not bind to control -->
<select
   ng-model="job.city" 
   ng-options="city.city_name as city.label for city in cites"
   name="city"
   class="form-control"
   required="" >                 
</select>

</form>
```

possible workaround which is slow as must wait for all 3 promises to resolve

```
var job = null;
api.getJobCategories()
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        $scope.jobCategories = responseObject.data;
        return api.getJob({
            job_id: $routeParams.job_id
        });
    })
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        job = responseObject.data; // store in temp var
        return api.getProvinceCities({
            province_name: job.province,
            asJson: true
        });
    })
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        $scope.cites = responseObject.data;
        $scope.job = job; // assign job scope only after cites select has been built
    });
```

suggestion by JB Nizet which works

```
var job, city;
job = city = null;
api.getJobCategories()
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        $scope.jobCategories = responseObject.data;
        return api.getJob({
            job_id: $routeParams.job_id
        });
    })
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        job = responseObject.data;
        city = job.city; // store city in temp var
        job.city = null; // or delete job.city 
        $scope.job = job;
        return api.getProvinceCities({
            province_name: job.province,
            asJson: true
        });
    })
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        $scope.cites = responseObject.data;
        $scope.job.city = city; // reassign city
    });
```

Comment: Can't you just store the job city in a temp variable and reassign it to the job once the cities are loaded?

Comment: @JBNizet Not the most elegant solution but it works thanks ;) I updated the question to reflect the suggestion

Comment: @ericsicons, I suggest you answer your own question instead of editing the question and leaving it hanging without answer even though it is technically solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggestion by JB Nizet which works

```
var job, city;
job = city = null;
api.getJobCategories()
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        $scope.jobCategories = responseObject.data;
        return api.getJob({
            job_id: $routeParams.job_id
        });
    })
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        job = responseObject.data;
        city = job.city; // store city in temp var
        job.city = null; // or delete job.city 
        $scope.job = job;
        return api.getProvinceCities({
            province_name: job.province,
            asJson: true
        });
    })
    .then(function (responseObject) {
        $scope.cites = responseObject.data;
        $scope.job.city = city; // reassign city
    });
```